# Battlefield game in ruby

Tags: ruby

This is a classic battleship game for two players:

```
#board1 and board2 arrays are boards that players see only dots (not bumped yet), O (not ship part) and X (bumped ship part) 
board1 = []
board2 = []

#Create the board that players can see through with terminal
for i in 0..4
    board1.append("O")
 end

 for i in 0..4
    board2.append("O")
 end

 def print_board(board1)
    for row in board1
        puts board1.map { |k| "#{k}" }.join("  ")
    end
end

def print_board(board2)
    for row in board2
        puts board2.map { |k| "#{k}" }.join("  ")
    end
end


print_board(board1)
puts "\n"
print_board(board2)

#array1 and array2 are obvious boards of player1 and player2 respectly 
array1 = [ [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ]
array2 = [ [1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] ]

#Starting of the game and the printing the board 
while true do
    puts "Welcome to the game!!!"
    puts "Do you want to start? (start/reset):"
    a = gets.chomp
    if a == 'start'

        for i in 0..100
            puts "Turn - Player1: "
            puts "Enter row: " 
            q = gets.chomp
            p1_row = q.to_i 
            puts "Enter coloumn: " 
            w = gets.chomp
            p1_col= w.to_i
            if array2[p1_row][p1_col] == 1
                array2[p1_row][p1_col] ="X"
                board2[p1_row][p1_col] ="X"
            elsif array2[p1_row][p1_col] == 0
                array2[p1_row][p1_col] ="-"
                board2[p1_row][p1_col] ="-"
            elsif array2[p1_row][p1_col] =="X" or array2[p1_row][p1_col] =="-"
                next
            end
            print_board(board2)

            puts "Turn - Player2: "
            puts "Enter row: " 
            e = gets.chomp
            p2_row = e.to_i 
            puts "Enter coloumn: " 
            r = gets.chomp
            p2_col= r.to_i
            if array1[p2_row][p2_col] == 1
                array1[p2_row][p2_col] ="X"
                board1[p2_row][p2_col] ="X"
            elsif array1[p2_row][p2_col] == 0
                array1[p2_row][p2_col] ="-"
                board1[p2_row][p2_col] ="-"
            elsif array1[p2_row][p2_col] =="X" or array1[p2_row][p2_col] =="-"
                next
            end
            print_board(board1)

         end

     elsif a == 'reset'
        puts "You are off the game"
        break
     else
        puts "\n"
        puts "Answer can be only {start} or {reset}"
     end
end
```

I have two problems with this code. When I entered index 4 for player 2, I get "index 4 out of string (IndexError)", but I did not find why. The other problem is that, when `if` statement finds 1 or 0, it changes all columns, and does not change only the element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is in your board set-up. You have

```
for i in 0..4
  board1.append("O")
end
```

But that only creates one dimension. Try this:

```
for i in 0..4
  board1[i] = []
  (0..4).each do
    board1[i].append("O")
  end
end
```

A secondary problem is the subroutine print_board. First, you only need one definition of the subroutine, then second, the map needs to apply to "row" not "board", like this:

```
def print_board(board)
  for row in board
    puts row.map { |k| "#{k}" }.join(" ")
  end
end
```

There are many other problems with your code. I assume you are learning Ruby and this is an exercise to learn the Array API. In such case, it will be best for you continue the exercise yourself, learning as you go.

However, one additional hint: Learn about rubocop and run it on your code. Doing this consistently will teach you about good Ruby style while also improving your code. To be specific: Install the rubocop gem, then run rubocop against your code like this:

```
rubocop -SEa battleship.rb
```